# Wamp Server Remembers Index Page and Icon

Tags: apache, wamp

I created an index.html and several other pages. I then put them in my Wamp Server www directory. They worked fine, but now I have deleted them and put only a file called m.php. But, whenever I go to localhost, I still see the index page. Also, ever since I changed the icon of the index page, any html file in localhost still has that icon, even after I deleted it and the index page. What is going on?

Comment: Where?  Which settings?

Comment: Do you mean "C:\wamp\wampmanager.ini"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a hard-refresh in your browser by pressing Ctrl-F5 on your keyboard while your website is in the window/tab. This will cause your browser to skip any caches and ignore existing expires headers on the files it pulled.

If that does not work, make sure you are actually working in the right folder, and also that you are not being redirected.

Comment: But the icon is still there! That is annoying.

Comment: @JohnSmith, the favicon.ico that is displayed by the URL box? Or an image in the page itself? In IE, press the Alt button, go to Tools, Delete Browser History (make sure Internet Files is selected)... It will be something similar for Firefox and Chrome.